# Ubuntu One oAuth token - time of life

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-one-api

I try to develop some Java application that works with Ubuntu One account. Everything is ok, I have access to my U1 space but I'm not sure of one thing. How long may I use my oAuth token? Has it some "time of life" just like Facebook token (about 60 days)?

Comment: The service is obsolete.